# qx.data.store.Jsonp: configureRequest not getting request as parameter

Tags: javascript, request, jsonp, qooxdoo

when creating an new qx.data.store.Jsonp object like this...

```
var store = new qx.data.store.Jsonp(url, {
  configureRequest: function(req) {
    req.setParameter("key", "resources.appsrvs");
  }
},"callback");
```

... the delegate function configureRequest does not get the request as parameter as described in qx.data.storeInterface.IStoreDelegate. so how can i configure the request?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, not in the way you intend. The Jsonp store uses a ScriptLoader object, as it is designed for *cross-domain requests*. So your delegate is used, but the 'req' object passed to it is actually a qx.io.ScriptLoader instance. Please see the API doc for [ScriptLoader](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.0.x/apiviewer/#qx.io.ScriptLoader) and also [here](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.0/data_binding/stores) for some additional details.

If you are not planning to do a cross-domain request, consider using qx.data.store.Json instead.

Comment: Unfortunately i am planning to make an cross domain request. But I found no way to "req.setParameter"  via "ScriptLoader". As workaround I add the parameter by string concatenation to the url  (url+"?key=resources.appsrvs"). Not nice, but works. So I have to care about url-escaping myself.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the fact that `qx.data.store.Jsonp` internally seems to use `qx.io.ScriptLoader` for which the documentation says `EXPERIMENTAL – NOT READY FOR PRODUCTION`.

Also you didn't specify which version of qooxdoo you use. Prior to 1.0.x I think `qx.data.store.Jsonp` is just an empty stub.

Does your function get called at all? If yes what does it get passes as parameters?

And finally consider just filing a bug report.

Comment: oh, sorry. i am using 1.0.1, and it is called. see other answer.